# How get sum of values in another dataframe based column value in first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': 'Red Red Blue'.split(), 'Value': [100, 150, 50]})
>>> df
  Color  Value
0   Red    100
1   Red    150
2  Blue     50
```

I have second data frame dfmain

```
dfmain = pd.DataFrame({'Color': ["Red","Blue","Yellow"]})
>>> dfmain
    Color
0     Red
1    Blue
2  Yellow
```

i want to get result data frame with sum of each colors 
my expected result is

```
>>> result
    Color  sum
0     Red  250
1    Blue   50
2  Yellow    0
```

Now i am using loop. its getting slow when run for large data set . I would like to get 
typical **pandas(or numpy)** solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating `sum` with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Color')['Value'].sum().reindex(dfmain.Color, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)

    Color  Value
0     Red    250
1    Blue     50
2  Yellow      0
```